# Using Handlebars, Gulp & Browserify without writing templates to disk

Tags: handlebars.js, browserify, gulp

Would love to do the following in a backbone view file that will be "browserified" during a gulpjs build:

```
var template = require('../templates/pathToUncompiledTemplate');
```

The catch seems to be that this Handlebars file isn't compiled, thus not a JS file. The build works if I compile the template first to a tmp directory:

```
var template = require('../compiledtemplates/pathToACompiledTemplate');
```

With the promise of streaming builds and no more tmp files, I'm hoping someone more experienced with Browserify, Gulp, or both could point me in the right direction. To be very specific, the goal is to compile the templates during a gulp task, while still using require statements that reference the original template files, thus avoiding temp files. Possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to use Gulp for that. Just use browserify transform for compiling handlebars templates — [browserify-handlebars](https://npmjs.org/package/browserify-handlebars).

```
% npm install browserify-handlebars
% browserify -t browserify-handlebars ./index.js
```

where `index.js` and its dependencies can references Handlebars templates via using `require(..)`:

```
var template = require('./template.handlebars');
var html = template({title: "An instantiated template!", name: "David"});
```

Note the `.handlebars` extension — this what this particular transform looking for to be activated for any concrete file.

Of course you can invoke the same browserify setup from Gulp and thus have it integrated into your Gulp build pipeline, if you already have one. Otherwise I suggest you to stick with plain browserify, it's a powerful tool on its own.

An example of doing this with Gulp:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var browserifyHandlebars = require('browserify-handlebars');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    // Single entry point to browserify
    gulp.src('src/js/app.js')
        .pipe(browserify({
          transform: [browserifyHandlebars]
          debug : !gulp.env.production
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'))
});
```

Comment: andreypopp, you've missed the point. Your answer puts it to disk. Absolutely need gulp (and previously needed a 400+ line grunt file) for all of the other tasks I'm running.

Comment: @ColinMegill, my answer only puts to disk a single file — a resulted bundle with all your JS and Handlebars templates. I thought the question was how to compile handlebars templates in memory, so browserify with corresponding transform does it. Gulp also should put something to disk eventually :-)

Comment: you don't grasp it, unfortunately. I already know everything you have said, and will restate again for future answers: can handlebars templates be compiled in a pipe in a gulp build task, and made available to a subsequent scripts task that has browserify style require calls for the compiled destination of the target, without writing the compiled templates to disk and referencing those.

Comment: @ColinMegill is doing template compilation and browserifying in separate gulp tasks a requirement here? Why?

Comment: @ColinMegill just FYI, I've updated the answer with a snippet of Gulpfile which uses browserify along with browserify-handlebars.